# How to return all last row's fields of the last Inserted/updated row?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, last-modified

As from title, I would like to return last row inserted/updated fields and values, is it possible in the same `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Usually not, sice you usually cannot combine SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use primary key, you can use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id); for example:

```
insert into user(name) values ('your name');
select * from user where id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If you need to get all row recently inserted or updated, I sugest to add INSERTED and UPDATED field with date time data type. So you can select your table with recently interval. See sample bellow:

```
SELECT *, INSERTED, UPDATED
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE INSERTED BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND NOW() 
   OR UPDATED BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND NOW();
```

this will return last one minute modified or inserted record.

Comment: I'm rather sure he wants to access the information, not insert it into the database.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() requires also AUTO_INCREMENT option.

Comment: the answer is not right cause i don't want only the last insert id i would like to return all row fields included id yep

Comment: all in same insert or update query, no separated queries i mean

Comment: INSERT and UPDATE do not return any datasets.

Comment: @Aaaaaaa, I suggest you add inserted and updated field with datetime type on your table. So you can filter your query by get latest (about 1 minute) inserted or updated value.

Comment: @hebibillah not understood very well sorry, can you show me in answer code example?

Comment: Use TIMESTAMP type with ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP option instead of DATETIME.

Comment: @habibillah i think i exaplained bad what i need and sorry for my english, but i don't want a SELECT qery i need to be able to select last inserted field inside a INSERT or UPDATE query, last row by selecting i know how to do that :P